# Draw a line from object to where camera is facing in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am starting out to create a minigolf game in Unity. I want to aim by draggin the screen with my mouse which rotates the camera around the ball. Basically I want to draw an aim line (line renderer or any other good method) from the ball to where the camera is pointing. Right now I just draw the line I want from beginning, but in the end I want it to rotate with the camera like the red line in picture below.

[image]

The code for rotating the camera is working great, where previousCameraPosition is set when I click the mouse and Rotate() is called when mouse button is being held down:

```
private void Rotate()
    {
        // Get the movement vector
        Vector3 cameraMoveDirection = previousCameraPosition - mainCamera.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        // Rotate around the ball
        mainCamera.transform.position = ballObject.transform.position;

        // Make the rotations
        mainCamera.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), cameraMoveDirection.y * 360);
        mainCamera.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), -cameraMoveDirection.x * 360, Space.World);

        // Set the camera a certain amount away from the ball
        mainCamera.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, -ballObject.transform.position.z*2.5f));

        // Update the previousCameraPosition during the movement
        previousCameraPosition = mainCamera.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }
```

I tried to create a helper object which was set to rotate exactly like the camera which made the line exactly like I wanted it, except it was backwards (180 degrees wrong, facing into the camera instead of away) and it was 1 unit long since it was normalized. I am stuck on this for far too long now, any help or guidance would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can simply use the camera's forward vector without having to deal with any `Quaternion` rotation at all:

```
var forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
```

Then what you actually seem to want is not exactly this direction but rather map it onto a flat XZ plane:

```
var actualForward = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(forward, Vector3.up).Normalized;
```

then finally you can use this direction to draw your line e.g. between the points

```
var startPoint = ball.position;
var endpoint = startPoint + actualForward * lineLength;
```

Comment: You are a genius, worked just like that! All I had to do was keep the y-value steady since I want it flat on ground. Thank you so much!!